# Adding an entity to a dataset

Tags: nlp, dataset, spacy, named-entity-recognition

It would be helpful if you could help me add a GPA entity to Spacey Model for the named entity since there is no GPA entity in the resume dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you do have the resume dataset which is already annotated **without GPA** available with you.

You may annotate the **entire train dataset** for GPA and then train a new spacy model. Training a spacy model is straight forward please check https://spacy.io/usage/training#quickstart

If you do not have the resume dataset, you might want to create your own smaller resume dataset where you would only annotate GPA  and train a new spacy model which only detects GPA. Then you can use your existing model to detect other entites and this model to detect GPAs. Note with this method you would parse your production data over 2 models.

To aid with your annotation process you can use any free annotation tools like Docanno(https://github.com/doccano/doccano) or Acharya(https://github.com/astutic/Acharya).